# What is the best way to allow the user to define an array size in my class instead of having a fixed variable, in this case 8

Tags: c++, arrays, class

This is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class array
{
private:
    int arr[8];
    int max;
    int min;
public:
    void get_arr();
    void maxmin();
    void display();
};

void array::get_arr()
{
    int size;
    cout << "How many elements would you like to enter?";
    cin >> size;
    cout << "Enter elements: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    max = arr[0];
    min = arr[0];
}

void array::maxmin()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (max < arr[i])
        {
            max = arr[i];
        }
        if (min > arr[i])
        {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }
}

void array::display()
{
    cout << "Largest is " << max;
    cout << "Smallest is " << min;
}

int main()
{
    array obj;
    obj.get_arr();
    obj.maxmin();
    obj.display();
}
```

The code I have so far compiles and works correctly. I am however fairly new to using classes and am working on example problems like this to get used to formatting code in this manner. I am looking for pointers on how to most efficiently format my code to take a users inputted "size" variable for the array and implement it into my functions.

Comment: Just use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) maybe?

Comment: Get a review here: [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If you don't want `std::vector`, look up `new` and `delete`. Also look up *the rule of three* and *copy&swap idiom*, as those are crucial for working with `new`/`delete` properly.

Comment: Copy and swap's not crucial, but dang, does it make it easy.

Comment: To clarify: You have working code with a fixed size array. Now you want to modify your existing code to allow the user to specify the size?

Comment: @user4581301 correct.

Comment: Mason, I had to ask you for clarification to confirm my suspicions. While I did not downvote, I won't fault whoever did for writing off the question and moving on to a clearer question. I recommend you re-word the question to make your goal crystal clear.

Comment: @user4581301 I have updated my title question to clarify.

Comment: Thank you. The most efficient way to do this is as πάνταῥεῖ suggests: use `std::vector` instead of the array. If this is disallowed by an assignment restriction, the next best thing is to pretend it's 1992 and follow up on  HolyBlackCat's suggestions.

Comment: @MasonpenguinHolder you prefer to implement the vector yourself to learn how to do, no ?

Comment: @bruno I know how to use vectors, but I am hard hearted on keeping my arrays haha. If you would like to post the "vector code" below feel free if someone looks up this thread in the future they may find it useful for their own purposes.

Comment: You can use a templated class to parameterize the array with a compile-time integer parameter(the standard library has an `array` class that does this for C++11 or 14, I can't remember which); or you can use `std::vector` for sizing the array at runtime.

Comment: To clarify, votes indicate general usefulness to future readers, which can be somewhat subjective. This is why we aggregate votes from the entire community. It is a democracy of sorts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't test it. Try it :)

```
class vector
{
private:
    std::vector<int> myvector;
    int max;
    int min;
public:
    void set_arr();
    void maxmin();
    void display();
};
void array::set_arr() // (set_arr not get_arr)
{

  int myint;
  int size;

  std::cout << "How many elements would you like to enter?";
  cin >> size;

  for(int i=0,i<size;i++){
    std::cin >> myint;
    this->myvector.push_back (myint);
  }

}
```

// use this->myvector.size() to find max and min